# Can't set xsl:variable using substring-after from attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have very limited experience with xslt so I can't seem to find the problem here.

In the XML I have multiple occurrences of distinct `graphic` elements like so:

```xml
<graphic xlink:href="someVariableText-gf01.tif"/>
<graphic xlink:href="someVariableText-gf02.tif"/>
<graphic xlink:href="someVariableText-gf03.tif"/>
```

I need to change the `xlink:href` preserving the unique numbers after `-gf`.

My code below:

```xml
<xsl:template match="graphic/@xlink:href">
    <xsl:variable name="aftergf" select="substring-after(., 'gf')"/>

    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('MyNewText-gf', $aftergf)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Gives me:

```xml
<graphic xlink:href="MyNewText-gf"/>
<graphic xlink:href="MyNewText-gf"/>
<graphic xlink:href="MyNewText-gf"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is all-right. The mistake must be someplace else. (I suspect a second template that matches `graphic/@xlink:href`.) Compare http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwd

Comment: Thanks but no other template targets either `graphic` or `@xlink:href`...

Comment: Paste your entire stylesheet and XML to that page and save it, I'll have a look.

Comment: The full XML is very large and there is another stylesheet been applied.. But I a reduced version and it does work indeed.... I will perform a detailed check on the other stylesheet. Thanks for pointing me to this page. It will be a huge help!

Comment: Luciano, I hope you found the error in the meantime? If not, in general, we can only help if you show us all of the relevant code. If your input and stylesheet are "very large" it is your duty to try and reduce the amount of code and make sure that the problem is still present.

Comment: Thanks. I did not find the problem yet but I am positive lies somewhere else in the processing pipeline. Should I just delete this question since the code does actually work??